# PathTooLongException while file exists

Tags: vb.net, windows

When trying to copy a file in VB, I get the following exception:

> System.IO.PathTooLongException was caught
>     HResult=-2147024690
>     Message=The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

It appears that the pathname + filename is indeed too long, 270 characters in total. But here is my question. How was it, in the first place, possible to create the file? And how is it possible that the file exists?

Comment: Here [**read this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22781021/why-path-getdirectoryname-function-has-to-be-dependent-on-260-chars-limit) it will explain in more detail. Do you have a specific issue as well?

Comment: Simple answer: it was created in a different way (not via absolute path through VB). Internally, Windows/the file system has no issue creating paths longer than 260 characters. There's just some front-end layers that restrict this, for legacy reasons.